# Offering a Windows 8 App together with a desktop application

Tags: windows-8, desktop-application, windows-store

I am looking to offer a Metro app with my desktop application. The problem is that users will be getting the desktop app, while the Metro app would just be a companion that is practically useless without the desktop application. So since it's not possible for consumers to get Win 8 apps without the Store (as far as I know at least) I am looking for alternatives. Is it, for example, possible to call the Windows Store during installation and get the user directly on the store page for the companion app? Even better, would it be possible to get that process automated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just have to document the fact that there is a sister app avalible from the store. As you know, this companion app would still have to undergoe the rigorous Microsoft test proceedure so could not be shipped with the desktop version. I suppose you could have a "Get Metro App" link somewhere in your main application that would go to your metro page ready for the download...

You will have to modularise the desktop app to work both with and without the Windows 8 Metro app (something I am sure you would do anyway).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know, someone else voted this down. I know this answer as I have just returned from a two day Microsoft Training course on Windows 8 application development and was talking to one of the guys about the possiblities of MS doing this for VS2012...

Answer (score 2):

Your app must be fully functional to pass Store certification.  You wrote ...

> "... Metro app would just be a companion that is practically useless
>   without the desktop application."

Section 1.2 of the [Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh694083) reads ...

> The Windows Store offers only fully functional apps to provide
>   customers with the best experience. Anything that might cause our
>   testers to think that your app is not completely finished will cause
>   your app to fail certification.

The testers will not install a companion app and therefore your app will fail certification.  It will also likely fail 1.1 ...

> Your app must offer customers unique, creative value or utility in all
>   the languages and markets that it supports

Comment: This was my first thought. I've spoken extensively with several MS team members and they are very particular about Store Apps being standalone and fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question if the "Store" app will be communicating with the desktop app.  If there is a requirement to have a desktop app installed in order to fully use the Store app, the certification process will be a lot more complicated.  You will need to supply a copy of the desktop app to the certification team for testing, and there is no guarantee that this sort of app will be accepted into the store.